# TestLink: How to copy test cases from one Testsuite to another Testsuite in Same Testplan

Tags: test-management, testcase, testlink

I have a testsuite A in which I have 6 test cases, and I want to copy it to testsuite B in the same Test Plan TS_1 in Same project 'X'.

First I Exported the test cases in XML format and then tried to import in testsuite "B" from import test cases operation, but it is showing an error message "Can not be imported - You are hitting an existent Test Case with SAME EXTERNAL ID:".

It gives this error even if I choose the option that if it has same External ID create a new version. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 6 test cases to copy, you can copy them only going to each case in Test Specification, select then one by one, and click in Copy / Move, it will give you the option to Copy or to Move. Only copy them to another folder and *voilá!*

For 10 or more test cases (manually it take more than 3 minutes), it will be better upgrade to test link 1.9.16, which have the importation problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to upgrade your version of TestLink.  There was an [issue](http://mantis.testlink.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=5812) that was fixed in TestLink version 1.9.8 that caused imports to break with that exact error message.

Comment: My present  testlink version is 1.9.13 .I am facing the above mentioned issue

Comment: – chandra kanth Chandra ; upgrade your Testlink version to 1.9.14

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 1.9.14 version

And you can copy it from one test suite for another very easily using the "move or copy" option in Action Box. Follow the steps in below;

1.First select the test suite.

2.Click on Action icon, and you'll get the all the options under that.

3.Choose a "target container" from drop down and select the "Destination position".

4.Click on "copy" button.

5.new test suite will create alone with the test cases.

6.Rename the Test Suite accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to click on the suit which you want to copy or move. After that click on Setting icon there you will get move or copy button. You can click on that and move or copy accordingly